# big-O and bounded functions

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

I keep seeing a property but I not sure what it is called or how exactly it works.  Each time I see it used it is with a, say $G()$, whose derivative is bounded, and an input $x + x_n$ where $x_n \approx O(n^{-1})$. Then I see that because of the boundedness (I think)

\begin{align*}
G(x + x_n) &\approx G\left (x + O(n^{-1})\right )\\
&\approx  G(x) + O(n^{-1})
\end{align*}

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Comment: Hint: what you really need is for $G$ to also have a bounded derivative. Then you can use the triangle inequality for integrals.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Do you have a link to help me learn more?  This isn't directly related to what I do, this is a side fact for the main thing I am working on.

Comment: You are also correct, the fact I was given was that the derivate of $G$ is bounded.  I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Lagrange mean value theorem we have $G(x + x_n) - G(x) = (x + x_n - x) \cdot G'(\xi)$, where $\xi$ is some point in $(x, x + x_n)$. Given that $G'$ is bounded, we have $|G'(\xi)| < M$ for some $M$ and all $\xi$, so $|G(x + x_n) - G(x)| < M \cdot x_n = O(x_n)$, or, equivalently, $G(x + x_n) = G(x) + O(x_n)$. If $x_n = O(n^{-1})$, this becomes $G(x + x_n) = G(x) + O(n^{-1})$.

Comment: This is so helpful!!! Do you have a resource you can recommend where I can find more about this?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, about derivatives - any calculus textbook, for example Rudin "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" (known as "Baby Rudin"). I think it doesn't talk about asymptotes. There should be some calculus books that do, but I don't remember any particular. There are covered in Knuth's "Concrete mathematics", but I doubt it's good source if you need only them (although it's a very good book by itself).